# WPF: Get the selected values ListView Binding

Tags: c#, wpf, listview

I got 2 listviews in the same window
The first listView which loads Image thumbnail & Image name. In the second list-view, I want to update the selected image name/name & propose the user to delete or view the selected Images by button click.

I followed this article (http://www.clear-lines.com/blog/post/Selecting-an-item-in-a-list-with-WPF-and-M-V-VM.aspx) but i couldn't succeed to get the selected items by binding.  How can i get the selected image name/names from the model.

Code:

```
//ImageFile Collection Model
 public class ImageFileCollectionViewModel: INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private ObservableCollection<ImageFileViewModel> _allImages;
        private int dataItemsCount;

        public ObservableCollection<ImageFileViewModel> AllImages
        {
            get { return _allImages; }
        }

        public int DataItemsCount
        {
            get
            {
                return dataItemsCount;
            }
            private set
            {
                dataItemsCount = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("DataItemsCount");
            }
        }

        public ImageFileCollectionViewModel()
        {
            this._allImages = new ObservableCollection<ImageFileViewModel>();
            this.DataItemsCount = 0;
        }

        public void AddNewPhotoItem(IImageFile imageFile)
        {
            ImageFileViewModel newImageFileViewModel = new ImageFileViewModel(imageFile);
            this._allImages.Add(newImageFileViewModel);
            this.DataItemsCount++;
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        private void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
        }

        public ImageFileViewModel ImageFileName { get; set; }// To get the selected Image name
    }
```

First ListView:

```
string destination_dir = System.IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + @"./4x6";
ImageFileCollectionViewModel ImagesViewModel = new ImageFileCollectionViewModel();
ImageFileControler.CompleteViewList(ImagesViewModel, destination_dir);
ListViewImage.DataContext = ImagesViewModel;
```

Xaml:

```
 <ListView  SelectionMode="Multiple"  x:Name="ListViewImage" Width="Auto" 
              ItemsSource="{Binding Path=AllImages}"  Margin="0,20,0,0"
              VirtualizingStackPanel.IsVirtualizing="True"
              VirtualizingStackPanel.VirtualizationMode= "Recycling" Height="333" VerticalAlignment="Top">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate.Resources>
                        <Storyboard x:Key="WaitingTimeline" Timeline.DesiredFrameRate="10">
                            <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="00:00:00" RepeatBehavior="Forever" 
                            Storyboard.TargetName="WaitingImage" 
                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[0]
                                                       .(RotateTransform.Angle)">
                                <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00" Value="-15"/>
                                <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:03" Value="15"/>
                            </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                        </Storyboard>
                    </DataTemplate.Resources>

                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Height="100">

                        <Image x:Name="ThumbnailImage" Margin="2" Visibility="Collapsed" Height="120" Width="180" Source="{Binding Path=Thumbnail}" >
                            <Image.BitmapEffect>
                                <DropShadowBitmapEffect ShadowDepth="5" />
                            </Image.BitmapEffect>

                        </Image>
                        <Image x:Name="WaitingImage" Visibility="Visible" Height="20" Width="20" Source="./Hourglass.png">
                            <Image.RenderTransform>
                                <TransformGroup>
                                    <RotateTransform Angle="0" CenterX="10" CenterY="10"/>
                                </TransformGroup>
                            </Image.RenderTransform>

                        </Image>

                        <TextBlock Margin="10,40,0,0" Text="{Binding Path=ShortName}" />
                    </StackPanel>

                    <DataTemplate.Triggers>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=IsLoaded}" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="Visibility" TargetName="ThumbnailImage" Value="Visible"/>
                            <Setter Property="Visibility" TargetName="WaitingImage" Value="Collapsed"/>
                        </DataTrigger>

                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=IsLoaded}" Value="False">
                            <Setter Property="Visibility" TargetName="WaitingImage" Value="Visible"/>
                            <Setter Property="Visibility" TargetName="ThumbnailImage" Value="Collapsed"/>
                            <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                                <BeginStoryboard x:Name="WaitingTimeline_BeginStoryboard" Storyboard="{StaticResource WaitingTimeline}"/>
                            </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                            <DataTrigger.ExitActions>
                                <StopStoryboard BeginStoryboardName="WaitingTimeline_BeginStoryboard"/>
                            </DataTrigger.ExitActions>
                        </DataTrigger>
                    </DataTemplate.Triggers>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>

        </ListView>
```

Second ListView to get the selected Image Name/names:

```
<StackPanel Name="secondLBox" Margin="53,369,10,31" Orientation="Vertical"  >
            <ListBox Height="65" 
                Name="ImageNameListBox" 
                ItemsSource="{Binding AllImages}" 
                DisplayMemberPath="LastName"
               SelectedItem="{Binding Path=ImageFileName}"/>
            <Label Content="Selected Image"/>
            <Label Content="{Binding ImageFileName.FileName}" Visibility="Visible" Height="39"/>

        </StackPanel>
```

Comment: Additionally to Rohits answer, if ImageViewModel.ImageFileName should contain the item selected in the ListView then I believe you should also bind ListView.SelectedItem to ImageViewModel.ImageFileName. (ListView.SelectedItem uses two-way binding by default)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Additionally to Rohits answer, if **ImageViewModel.ImageFileName** should contain the selected item from the ListView then you also need to bind **ListView.SelectedItem** to ImageViewModel.ImageFileName. (ListView.SelectedItem uses two-way binding by default)

```
<ListView
    SelectedItem="{Binding Path=ImageFileName}"
    ... all your other stuff from the XAML
/>
```

*ListView.SelectedItem* binds two-way by default, so if you change *ImageViewModel.ImageFileName* via code-behind or through another binding, the selection in the ListView will change accordingly (assuming you also followed Rohit's advice).

You also have an error in the ListBox preventing you to see *ImageViewModel.ImageFileName*.

Note that the listbox contains items of type **ImageViewModel**, because of:

```
<ListBox
    ItemsSource="{Binding AllImages}"
    ...
/>
```

Now, any possible selected item would also be an **ImageViewModel**, not *ImageViewModel.FileName*. Hence, your ListBox should be set up similar to this:

```
<ListBox Height="65" 
    ItemsSource="{Binding AllImages}" 
    SelectedItem="{Binding ImageFileName}"
    DisplayMemberPath="FileName.LastName"
    ...
/>
```

**UPDATE**:

Squinting my eyes very hard, another likely problem was spotted in the code.

The *ImageFileCollectionViewModel* supposedly serving as DataContext for the ListView **and** the ListBox is *only* assigned to *ListView.DataContext*.

To have the *ImageFileCollectionViewModel* also applied as DataContext of the *ListBox*, either assign it explicetly:

```
ImageFileCollectionViewModel ImagesViewModel = new ImageFileCollectionViewModel();
ImageFileControler.CompleteViewList(ImagesViewModel, destination_dir);
ListViewImage.DataContext = ImagesViewModel;
ImageNameListBox.DataContext = ImagesViewModel;
```

or just set the DataContext at the parent/ancestor container UIElement, if both the ListView and the ListBox happen to share the same parent/ancestor.

Comment: I followed exactly yours & Rohits still i don't see any value.

Comment: You might need to do `DisplayMemberPath="(FileName.LastName)"` (note the parantheses) because of the dot. But i am not entirely sure whether you need to do it, as i currently don't have a way to verify this.

Comment: I'm pretty sure, you guys are right but still i don't see the value. Can i share the skydrive link because I would like to fix this problem?

Comment: Bring it on :) (But beware, i don't have VS at my hands so i will have to do with my lousy memory ;) )

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/45581/discussion-between-elgonzo-and-linguini)

Answer (score 1):

Property `ImageFileName` should raise `PropertyChange event` on any change in property content so that UI can refresh accordingly.

Declaration should be like this:

```
private ImageFileViewModel imageFileName;
public ImageFileViewModel ImageFileName
{
   get
   {
      return imageFileName;
   }
   set
   {
      if(imageFileName != value)
      {
         imageFileName = value;
         OnPropertyChanged("ImageFileName");
      }
   }
}
```

---

If you want both ListBox to be in sync:

1. Bind SelectedItem for first ListBox with ImageFileName.
2. Bind SelectedItem for second ListBox with SelectedItem of first ListBox.

First ListBox:

```
<ListBox Name="ListViewImage" 
         SelectedItem="{Binding ImageFileName}"/>
```

Second ListBox:

```
<ListBox Name="ImageNameListBox" 
         SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem, ElementName=ListViewImage}"/>
```

Comment: Yep, i forgot thank you. Still I don't see any value the second list-view when i click in the first LV.

Comment: @linguini, see my comment below your question (i did put it as a comment, since i first wasn't sure of what exactly you tried to achieve)

Comment: @linguini- See the update in answer. Hope i understood your problem correctly.